# pip show boto3 - missing classifiers

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

```
I am comparing boto3 of two Amazonlinux instances(server1 and server 2). I can see classifiers are missing in server 2 . 

Server 1: 

[root@xxxxx]: pip show boto3
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: boto3
Version: 1.2.3
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: UNKNOWN
Installer: pip
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
**Requires: jmespath, futures, botocore
****Classifiers:****
  Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
  Intended Audience :: Developers
  Natural Language :: English
  License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
  Programming Language :: Python
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4**



Server 2:
[root@xxxxx]# pip show boto3
Name: boto3
Version: 1.17.112
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: None
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
**Requires: jmespath, s3transfer, botocore
**Required-by:****
```

Can you help in adding the classifiers to server 2 (pip show boto3). I want to make sure server 1 and server 2 should show same result of pip show boto3 especially in classifiers

Comment: **Why**? this must be an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: You should only rely on the installed version of `boto3`, not on the output of `pip show` which may change depending on the version of `pip`